# Sign up — Two models, One form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid

I'm working with Rails 3.1, Devise and Mongoid. Right now I have 3 models — User, Client < User and Developer < User. Is there a way to sign up as either client or a developer from one form using say radio for checking desired account type?

It seems like I can edit only devise's views but not make some changes to controller. Or now?

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby (then in Rails), you can redefine whatever you want, whenever you need.

So indeed, you can redefine the controller if you want to and override one or several actions.

Just create the controller file at the same level it's in the gem itself, or make good use of `class_eval`.

Using Devise, make sure you add your additional attributes in the `attr_accessible` list.

Comment: Nope, it's not so easy to do so w/ Devise

Comment: Please give details because it's what I do